# Animated magazine

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How can I write this code better? I'm doing an animated magazine, so I run and then clean the animation per page.

```
magazine.turn({
                width:  MGZ_WIDTH,
                height: MGZ_HEIGHT,
                pages:MAGAZINE_PAGES,
                display:DISPLAY_PAGE,
                acceleration: !isChrome(),
                autoCenter: false,
                when:{
                    missing: function (e, pages) {                      
                        for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                            addPage(pages[i], $(this));
                        }
                    },
                    turning: function(e, page, view) {
                        removeShadow(page);
                        $(this).turn('page');
                        Hash.go('page/' + page).update();
                        removeAnimationCache(page);
                    },
                    turned: function(e, page, view) {
                        addShadow(page);
                        animatePage(page);
                    }
                }
            });

function animatePage(page) {

        // var display_value;
        // if ( DISPLAY_PAGE === 'double') {
        //     display_value = 1;
        // }
        // if ( DISPLAY_PAGE === 'single') {
        //     display_value = 2;
        // }
        console.log(page);

        if (page===1){

           $('.img-logo-an').each(function(i) {
                var step = i + 1;
                $(this).animate({ 
                    opacity: 0.9 }, 1500 * step, function() {
                    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0}, 3000 * step);
                });
            });

           $('.img-logo-an-2').each(function(i) {
                var step = i + 2;
                $(this).animate({ 
                    opacity: 1 }, 2780 * step, function() {
                    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0}, 2902 * step);
                });
            });

           $('.p2').find('.car_logo').stop(true).removeAttr('style');
        }
        if (page === 2 || page === 3) {
            $('.p2').find('.car_logo')
                    .animo( { animation: 'bounceInLeft', duration: 3, timing: 4 } )
                    .css({opacity:1});
        }

        if (page === 16 || page === 17) {
            $('.p16').find('.robo')
                    .animo( { animation: 'bounceInLeft', duration: 2.5 } )
                    .css({opacity:1});
            $('.p17').find('.chic')
                    .animo( { animation: 'bounceInRight', duration: 2.5 } )
                    .css({opacity:1});
        }

        if (page === 24 || page === 25) {
            $('.p25').find('.video-container')
                    .delay(1000)
                    .animate({ opacity:1});
        }
        if (page === 36 || page === 37) {
            $('.p36').find('.tuum-logo')
                    .delay(1000)
                    .animo({ animation:'tada' })
                    .css({opacity:1});              

            $('.p36').find('.colgante')
                    .animate({opacity:1}, 2300);
        }

        if (page === 58 || page === 59) {
            $('.p58 .p58-1').delay(1).fadeIn(1);
            $('.p58 .p58-2').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            $('.p58 .p58-3').delay(350).fadeIn(200);
            $('.p58 .p58-4').delay(500).fadeIn(200);
            $('.p58 .p58-5').delay(650).fadeIn(200);


            $('.p58 .p58-7').delay(650)
                .animate({ opacity: 1}, function() {
                    $('.p58 .p58-8')
                        .animate({ top : 0, opacity: 1 }, 1000, function() {
                            $('.p58 .p58-6').css({opacity: 1});
                        });
            });
            // 
        }


        if (page === 114 || page === 115) {

            $('.p114').find('.letter-1').delay(1600).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-2').delay(2000).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-3').delay(400).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-4').delay(200).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-5').delay(1).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-6').delay(2300).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-7').delay(4500).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-8').delay(4000).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-9').delay(3800).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-10').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-11').delay(3500).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-12').delay(800).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-13').delay(3200).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-14').delay(1000).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-15').delay(1400).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-16').delay(3000).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-17').delay(1200).fadeIn(100);
            $('.p114').find('.letter-18').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
        }


    } // end animatePage

    function removeAnimationCache(page) {

        if (page === 4) {
            $('.p2').find('.car_logo').stop(true).removeAttr('style');
        }

        if (page === 15 || page === 18) {
            $('.p16').find('.robo')
                    .stop(true)
                    .removeAttr('style');
            $('.p17').find('.chic')
                    .stop(true)
                    .removeAttr('style');
        }

        if (page === 35 || page === 38) {
            $('.p36').find('.tuum-logo')
                    .stop(true)
                    .removeAttr('style');
            $('.p36').find('.colgante')  
                    .stop(true)
                    .removeAttr('style');               
        }

        if (page === 57 || page === 60) {
            $('.p58').find('.p58-img').each(function(){
                $(this).stop(true).removeAttr('style');
            });
            $('.p58').find('.p58-img-animated').each(function(){
                $(this).stop(true).removeAttr('style');
            });

        }

        if (page === 113 || page === 116) {
            $('.p114').find('.letter').each(function(){
                $(this).stop(true).removeAttr('style');
            });

        }

    } // end removeAnimationCache
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not just what would be the best way to refactor your code, but I still have some tips for you. I'll take parts of your code and show you how I would have done using a before/after approach:

## Snippet 1

#### Before

```
magazine.turn({
                width:  MGZ_WIDTH,
                height: MGZ_HEIGHT,
                pages:MAGAZINE_PAGES,
                display:DISPLAY_PAGE,
                acceleration: !isChrome(),
                autoCenter: false,
                when:{
                    missing: function (e, pages) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                            addPage(pages[i], $(this));
                        }
                    },
                    turning: function(e, page, view) {
                        removeShadow(page);
                        $(this).turn('page');
                        Hash.go('page/' + page).update();
                        removeAnimationCache(page);
                    },
                    turned: function(e, page, view) {
                        addShadow(page);
                        animatePage(page);
                    }
                }
            });
```

#### After

```
magazine.turn({
    width:  MGZ_WIDTH,
    height: MGZ_HEIGHT,
    pages:MAGAZINE_PAGES,
    display:DISPLAY_PAGE,
    acceleration: !isChrome(),
    autoCenter: false,
    when:{
        missing: function (e, pages) {
            for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                addPage(pages[i], $(this));
            }
        },
        turning: function(e, page, view) {
            removeShadow(page);
            $(this).turn('page');
            Hash.go('page/' + page).update();
            removeAnimationCache(page);
        },
        turned: function(e, page, view) {
            addShadow(page);
            animatePage(page);
        }
    }
});
```

#### What changed

- choose an indentation style and stick with it. Don't mix indentation with tabs and space, don't mix with one tab indentation with two tabs indentation, don't mix 2 spaces indentation with 16 spaces indentation: it's hard to follow your code

## Snippet 2

#### Before

```
missing: function (e, pages) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        addPage(pages[i], $(this));
    }
},
```

#### After

```
missing: function (e, pages) {
    var $this = $(this);
    for (var i = 0, len=pages.length; i < len; i++) {
        addPage(pages[i], $this);
    }
},
```

#### What changed

- Use a local variable `len` to cache the `pages.length` value. This avoid calling `pages.length` multiples times and improves *a bit* the for loop performance
- cache `jQuery` objects and don't call to `$(whatever)` multiple times. Since you're calling `$(this)` in the loop, you're calling it multiples times. When you call `$(whatever)`, you're creating a new `jQuery` object, and this object creation has a non-negligible performance cost for the browser. Avoid calling it multiples times wherever you can. This tip can be applied a lot in your current code (I highlight some places below)

## Snippet 3

#### Before

```
$('.img-logo-an').each(function(i) {
    var step = i + 1;
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.9 }, 1500 * step, function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0}, 3000 * step);
    });
});
```

#### After

```
$('.img-logo-an').each(function imgLogoEachLoop(i) {
    function onComplete() {
        $this.animate({opacity: 0}, 3000 * step);
    }

    var step = i + 1;
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({opacity: 0.9}, 1500 * step, onComplete);
});
```

#### What changed

- cache `jQuery` objects as above
- avoid strange code structure and indentation by inlining function as you did. In my example, we can clearly see what are three arguments in this call: `$this.animate({opacity: 0.9}, 1500 * step, onComplete);`. To me, you're snippet lacks of readability
- declare the internal function `onComplete` at the begining of the outer function: this avoid strange behavior with JavaScript
- avoid anonymous function to improve debugging experience: this turns errors like `Uncaught exception on function '(anonymous function)'` into `Uncaught exception on function 'imgLogoEachLoop'`

## Snippet 3

#### Before

```
$('.p36').find('.tuum-logo')
        .delay(1000)
        .animo({ animation:'tada' })
        .css({opacity:1});

$('.p36').find('.colgante')
        .animate({opacity:1}, 2300);
```

#### After

```
var TUUMLOGO_SHOW_DELAY = 1000;
var COLGANTE_SHOW_DURATION = 2300;

var $p36 = $('.p36');

$p36.find('.tuum-logo')
    .delay(TUUMLOGO_SHOW_DELAY)
    .animo({ animation:'tada' })
    .css({opacity:1});

$p36.find('.colgante').animate({opacity:1}, COLGANTE_SHOW_DURATION);
```

#### What changed

- here again, cache `jQuery` objects
- don't mix indentation style (I stick with 4 spaces indentation in all my *Before* examples so I've update your indentation here)
- don't use "magic numbers": `1000` and `2300` were magic numbers to me. Declare some constants early in the code and use those constant when needed. The next snippet has a better example for this point.

## Snippet 4

#### Before

```
$('.p58 .p58-1').delay(1).fadeIn(1);
$('.p58 .p58-2').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
$('.p58 .p58-3').delay(350).fadeIn(200);
$('.p58 .p58-4').delay(500).fadeIn(200);
$('.p58 .p58-5').delay(650).fadeIn(200);
```

#### After

```
// declare this early in the code...
var FADEIN_DURATION = 200;
var START_DELAY = 200;
var ADDITIONAL_DELAY = 150;


// ... and this later on
var $p58 = $('.p58');

$p58.find('.p58-1').delay(1).fadeIn(1);
$p58.find('.p58-2').delay(START_DELAY + 0*ADDITIONAL_DELAY).fadeIn(FADEIN_DURATION);
$p58.find('.p58-3').delay(START_DELAY + 1*ADDITIONAL_DELAY).fadeIn(FADEIN_DURATION);
$p58.find('.p58-4').delay(START_DELAY + 2*ADDITIONAL_DELAY).fadeIn(FADEIN_DURATION);
$p58.find('.p58-5').delay(START_DELAY + 3*ADDITIONAL_DELAY).fadeIn(FADEIN_DURATION);
```

#### What changed

- don't use magic numbers: your values 250, 350, 500 and 650 are clearly following the formula `200 + 150x` ==> make this appears in your code, and as a bonus it will be easier to switch to a formula like `250 + 320x` because you just have to change the constants. In this example the line `START_DELAY + 0*ADDITIONAL_DELAY` could definitely be written as `START_DELAY` but I've write it that way to emphasis the formula even more
- keep `jQuery` selectors as simple as possible: this code `$('.p58').find('.p58-1')` performs *a bit* better than this one `$('.p58 .p58-1')`. Under the hood, `$('.p58')` and `.find('.p58-1')` relies on `document.getElementsByClassName` browser's native method, whereas `$('.p58 .p58-1')` needs at first a selector parsing step
- cache `jQuery` objects and reuse them. Once you've got the `$('.p58')` `jQuery` object, don't recreate it: cache it and reuse it performs better.

## Snippet 5

#### Before

```
$('.p58 .p58-7').delay(650)
    .animate({ opacity: 1}, function() {
        $('.p58 .p58-8')
            .animate({ top : 0, opacity: 1 }, 1000, function() {
                $('.p58 .p58-6').css({opacity: 1});
            });
});
```

#### After

```
function showP588() {
    $p58.find('.p58-8').animate({ top : 0, opacity: 1 }, 1000, showP586);
}
function showP586() {
    $p58.find('.p58-6').css({opacity: 1});
}

$p58.find('.p58-7').delay(650).animate({ opacity: 1}, showP588);
```

#### What changed

- all the same things are the previous snippet
- avoid strange code structure and indentation by inlining callback functions in `.animate` calls. Honestly, which one of those code snippets is easier to read ? This code `$p58.find('.p58-7').delay(650).animate({ opacity: 1}, showP588);` says: after some delay, animate the `.p58-7` element, and when you're done show the P588 element. Having function make it easier to read, as do having a meaningful name. Also, do you know to what this `});` corresponds at the end of your snippet ? We have to *search for* the corresponding brackets, which you shouldn't have to.

## Snippet 6

#### Before

```
$('.p114').find('.letter-1').delay(1600).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-2').delay(2000).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-3').delay(400).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-4').delay(200).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-5').delay(1).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-6').delay(2300).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-7').delay(4500).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-8').delay(4000).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-9').delay(3800).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-10').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-11').delay(3500).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-12').delay(800).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-13').delay(3200).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-14').delay(1000).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-15').delay(1400).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-16').delay(3000).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-17').delay(1200).fadeIn(100);
$('.p114').find('.letter-18').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
```

#### After

```
var $p14 = $('.p114');

var values = {
    1: {delay: 1600, duration: 100 },
    2: {delay: 2000, duration: 100 },
    3: {delay: 400, duration: 100 },
    4: {delay: 200, duration: 100 },
    5: {delay: 1, duration: 100 },
    6: {delay: 2300, duration: 100 },
    7: {delay: 4500, duration: 100 },
    8: {delay: 4000, duration: 100 },
    9: {delay: 3800, duration: 100 },
    10: {delay: 600, duration: 100 },
    11: {delay: 3500, duration: 100 },
    12: {delay: 800, duration: 100 },
    13: {delay: 3200, duration: 100 },
    14: {delay: 1000, duration: 100 },
    15: {delay: 1400, duration: 100 },
    16: {delay: 3000, duration: 100 },
    17: {delay: 1200, duration: 100 },
    18: {delay: 600, duration: 100 },
};

for (var i in values)
{
    var value = values[i];
    $p14.find('.letter-' + i).delay(value.delay).fadeIn(value.duration);
}
```

#### What changed

- same old tip: cache and reuse `jQuery` objects
- I hate doing the same thing again and again so I've put values into an object and I step trough this object to call the `fadeIn` method. It might be a bit too much here, but this would allow you to externalize or generate those values elsewhere.

## Snippet 7

#### Before

```
$('.p58').find('.p58-img').each(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).removeAttr('style');
});
$('.p58').find('.p58-img-animated').each(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).removeAttr('style');
});
```

#### After

```
var $p58 = $('.p58');

$p58.find('.p58-img').stop(true).removeAttr('style');
$p58.find('.p58-img-animated').stop(true).removeAttr('style');
```

#### What changed

- cache and reuse `jQuery` objects
- don't call `.each` whenever it's not needed. Both `.stop` and `.removeAttr` work when there is multiple elements in the `jQuery` object: this means that they're already calling `.each` under the hood, so you don't need to call it you here. What's strange is that this is exactly what you were doing just before this snippet (`$('.p36').find('.tuum-logo').stop(true).removeAttr('style');`)

## Snippet 8

#### Before

```
$('.p36').find('.colgante')
    .stop(true)
    .removeAttr('style');

$('.p58').find('.p58-img-animated').each(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).removeAttr('style');
});
```

#### After

```
$('.p36').find('.colgante')
    .stop(true)
    .removeAttr('style');

$('.p58').find('.p58-img-animated').each(function(){
    $(this)
        .stop(true)
        .removeAttr('style');
});
```

#### What changed

- be constant in your code style. Why the first `stop` call is on a new line when the second call is not ? Try to choose a style and stick with it, it'll improve global readability of the code

I've highlighted some points here, but please note that I've not fixed *all* points in *all* your code. For example, I've shown some places where you can cache `jQuery` objects, but your code may still contains some others places where this tip is available too. And this is true for all tips.

Here are my two cents for you. Hope this'll help you.